# Mank, oil, pew, or IQ?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

> Mank, oil, pew, or IQ?

What is special (*very* special) about this sentence?

Hint:

> Don't be distracted by the literal meaning of the words; that's completely irrelevant.

Comment: Observation: (rot13) Gur yrggre qvfgevohgvba vf ovnfrq gbjneqf gur pragre bs gur nycunorg, naq njnl sebz gur pragre bs gur [xrlobneq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29TAA.png).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

These letters,

> when taken as values 1-26, modulo 10, give the digits of pi.

That is,

> (Mank oil pew or iq) gives (13,1,14,11, 15,9,12, 16,5,23, 15,18, 9,17), for 3[.]1415926535897.

Next would be

> 9323, with the options of [is][cmw][blv][cmw], so we're kind of stuck. I haven't checked to see whether other choices earlier might let this go on longer, but it looks like the most we could do to extend this (without backtracking) is replace "IQ" with "IQs".

Comment: Bingo! You got it. What do you reckon - was this a unique solution, or too random / not special enough?